# I need to filter a list with a 'Time' column so that user can see his created items in the list when that day appears?

Tags: list, javascript

I need to filter a list with a 'Time' column, so that user can see his created items in the list when that day appears?

It should be for an AMPM view , Day of the week and Which week's day of the month like first monday, second tuesday etc?

I have tried out some ways to do this like adding a content editor on the web part and then modifying its HTML editor source but I am unable to make any changes to the content editor. Can it be done or there could be another alternative to it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your time column is a date time field, you could create a view where Created By equals [Me] and Date Time field is equal to [Today] all within the list view settings, no code required.

Answer (score 0):

I answer only for the Time.

I added a calculated column (Text type) with following formula
=TEXT([Start Date],"hh:mm")

hope this help you